# R: clustering with a similarity or dissimilarity matrix? And visualizing the results

Tags: r, matrix, similarity, dendrogram

I have a similarity matrix that I created using **Harry**—a tool for string similarity, and I wanted to plot some dendrograms out of it to see if I could find some clusters / groups in the data. I'm using the following similarity measures:

- Normalized compression distance (NCD)
- Damerau-Levenshtein distance
- Jaro-Winkler distance
- Levenshtein distance
- Optimal string alignment distance (OSA)

("For comparison Harry loads a set of strings from input, computes the specified similarity measure and writes a matrix of similarity values to output")

At first, it was like my first time using R, I didn't pay to much attention on the documentation of `hclust`, so I used it with a *similarity matrix*. I know I should have used a *dissimilarity matrix*, and I know, since my *similarity matrix* is normalized [0,1], that I could just do *dissimilarity = 1 - similarity* and then use `hclust`.

But, the groups that I get using `hclust`with a *similarity matrix* are much better than the ones I get using `hclust`and it's correspondent *dissimilarity matrix*.

I tried to use the `proxy` package as well and the same problem, the groups that I get aren't what I expected, happens.

To get the dendrograms using the similarity function I do:

1. `plot(hclust(as.dist(""similarityMATRIX""), "average"))`

With the dissimilarity matrix I tried:

2. `plot(hclust(as.dist(""dissimilarityMATRIX""), "average"))`

and

3. `plot(hclust(as.sim(""dissimilarityMATRIX""), "average"))`

From (1) I get what I believe to be a very good dendrogram, and so I can get very good groups out of it. From (2) and (3) I get the same dendrogram and the groups that I can get out of it aren't as good as the ones I get from (1)

I'm saying that the groups are bad/good because at the moment I have a somewhat little volume of data to analyse, and so I can check them very easily.

Does this that I'm getting makes any sense? There is something that justify this? Some suggestion on how to cluster with a similarity matrizx. Is there a better way to visualize a similarity matrix than a dendrogram?

Comment: You mention that you are using three similarity measures,  but all of them are called  `Something Distance` implying Dissimilarity measures.

Comment: It's hard to help without some data to work on. When writing a question, keep in the back of your mind the thought "how can I best make it easy for others to help me?". The answer in 9 out of 10 times is to post a chunk of code a potential answerer can simply copy/paste into their own editor, run it, and identically reproduce (a core part of) the issue you are having.

Comment: @G5W - From your comment and by looking again to the way these "something distance" seem to work, I believe you are correct and they, in fact, compute the dissimilarity between two strings. Since they basically analyze what it take (deletions, insertions, etc...) to transform one string into another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can visualize a similarity matrix using a heatmap (for example, using the [heatmaply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=heatmaply) R package). 
You can check if a dendrogram fits by using the dendextend R package function `cor_cophenetic` (use the most recent version from [github](https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/)).

Clustering which is based on distance can be done using hclust, but also using cluster::pam (k-medoids).